# Doctrine2 Prefix and zf2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, prefix

I'm working on prefix table on Doctrine :
[Doctrine Prefix](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/sql-table-prefixes.html)

but I don't know what `$config` is in :

```
$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config, $evm);
```

I found that :

```
$config = \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array( ??? ));
```

but what is `???` in my example.

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

The fields are as follows:

```
 * @param array   $paths
 * @param boolean $isDevMode
 * @param string  $proxyDir
 * @param Cache   $cache
 * @param bool    $useSimpleAnnotationReader
```

Not sure if this will help but I always do this when doing custom stuff ...

```
   use Doctrine\Common\EventManager;
   use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;
   use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
   use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;

   // Class definition and method ... {

    $params = 'orm_default' => array(
            'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
            'params' => array(
                'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
                'dbname'   => 'dbname',
                'user'     => 'myuser',
                'password' => 'mypass',
            ),
        );

    $eventManager = new EventManager();
    $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(), false, 'data/DoctrineORMModule/Proxy', null, false);
    $connection = DriverManager::getConnection($params,
                                               $config,
                                               $eventManager
    );
    $objectManager = EntityManager::create($connection, $config, $eventManager);
```

Comment: Thank you. I try that ASAP.